# Is it possible to switch to Mobile View in Selenium for the current driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am aware of creating a new instance of the web driver and switching it from desktop to mobile view by using: `options.EnableMobileEmulation("iPhone 6");`. But, is there a way where I can switch the current browser instance into Mobile view? Let say I have a browser open and I do a search on Google, but then the same driver session I switch/emulate to Mobile View... Is it possible, if so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

To a limited extent you can emulate mobile view by reducing the browser window size:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(240, 360);
```

This should be enough to trigger the break points in a responsive design-based layout. You'll have additional challenges waiting for the layout to change, since some elements might disappear, while others appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>(); mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "iPhone 6");

Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>(); chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```